# injectable_generator:injectable_builder on lib/src/core/di/register_modules.dart (cached):

Tags: flutter, dart, dependency-injection

```
injectable_generator:injectable_builder on lib/src/core/di/register_modules.dart (cached):
```

This is the error I have been getting whenever I try to `flutter pub run build_runner build` on my senior's code and I cannot find any solution to it. I just upgraded all the packages and fixed some minor UI changes and a data model which wasn't working due to change in response from server.

I couldn't find much on what is causing this error.

From what I know, it seems like the problem with dependency injection on `regestry_module` but cannot figure out what.

I tried clean and rebuild, pub upgrades and all still getting this error.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code where the error occours as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE

create a new file in root directory and name it build.ymal

```
global_options:
  auto_route_generator:autoRouteGenerator:
    runs_before:
      - injectable_generator:injectable_builder
```

add these lines there and it will work